# Angular unit Routing testing : Separate Routes testing sequence

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, routes, karma-jasmine

I have to test my Angular app routing :

Here is my routes declaration file :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome/welcome.component';
import { CustomersListComponent } from './customer/customers-list/customers-list.component';
import { CustomerDetailComponent } from './customer/customer-detail/customer-detail.component';
import { ApplicationParametersComponent } from './superAdministrator/application-parameters/application-parameters.component';
import { InscriptionComponent } from './inscription/inscription.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'login/:keyWording',  component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
  { path: 'customers-list', component: CustomersListComponent },
  { path: 'customer-create', component: CustomerDetailComponent },
  { path: 'customer-detail/:idCustomer', component: CustomerDetailComponent },
  { path: 'application-parameters', component: ApplicationParametersComponent },
  { path: 'inscription', component: InscriptionComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The following is my test file : 
**app-routing.spec.ts :**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
// DevExtreme Module
import {DxProgressBarModule, DxTemplateModule} from 'devextreme-angular';
// Router Modules
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
// Services and HTTP Module
import { SessionService } from './../shared/service';
import { HttpService } from './../shared/service';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
// Routs testing
import {Router, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {routes} from './app-routing.module';
import {fakeAsync, tick} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {WelcomeComponent} from './welcome/welcome.component';
import {ApplicationParametersComponent} from './superAdministrator/application-parameters/application-parameters.component';
import {InscriptionComponent} from './inscription/inscription.component';
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {CustomerDetailComponent} from './customer/customer-detail/customer-detail.component';
import {CustomersListComponent} from './customer/customers-list/customers-list.component';

describe('Testing the application routes', () => {

  let location: Location;
  let router: Router;
  let fixture;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)
        , FormsModule , DxTemplateModule , HttpModule ],
      providers: [SessionService , HttpService ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        WelcomeComponent,
        ApplicationParametersComponent,
        InscriptionComponent,
        CustomersListComponent,
        CustomerDetailComponent
      ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]

    });
    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    location = TestBed.get(Location);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    router.initialNavigation();
  });

  it('navigate to nothing  takes you to /login', () => {
    router.navigate(['']).then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toBe('/login');
    });
  });
```

The problem is that when i execute this , it works fine , since it contains ,**only on**e test case.

**The problem is when i add a second one** , for example i add this :

```
  it('navigate to "inscription" takes you to /inscription', () => {
    router.navigate(['/inscription']).then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toBe('/inscription');
    });
  });
```

i got an error which shows something interfering between routes :

```
Expected '/inscription' to be '/login'.
    at webpack:///src/app/app-routing.spec.ts:65:30 <- src/test.ts:144329:37
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:1546:26)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.Array.concat.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- src/test.ts:232587:39)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:1545:32)
```

I think that i should use the **afterEach()** loop to fix it , but i don't know how to do it exactly

Answer (score 0):

i get work by adding a simple:

```
tick(50)
```

pour chaque test case.

here it the structure of the test case :

```
  it('navigate to nothing  takes you to /login', () => {
    router.navigate(['']).then(() => {
      tick(50);
      expect(location.path()).toBe('/login');
    });
  });
```